# In SQL, how to retrieve information from relational database schema?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, relational-database

I have a relational database schema looks like:
[image]

The question is to 'find details of customers who bought products in 2009 and the products were manufactured by Honeywell in 1968'.

What I've done so far is:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE CID IN
    (SELECT Customer_ID FROM Order
     WHERE Purchase_Date = 2009 
     AND EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM Order_Items, Product, Manufacturer
         WHERE OID = OID AND Product_ID = PID AND MID = Manufacturer_ID AND
         Mnufacturer_Name = "Honeywell" AND Manufacturerd_Date = 1968));
```

I've been studying database for only about a month, so I guess it would look so complicate to expert people here.. Did I do this correctly ? Otherwise, please give any feedback where to fix..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically when retrieving information from related tables in a relational database, you should [**`JOIN`**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the tables using a join type that suits the results you need to get from the query. Whether including not matched rows from the outer table or not. So, in your case you can do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.*
FROM Customer c
INNER JOIN Order        o ON c.CID             = o.Customer_ID
INNER JOIN OrderItems  oi ON o.OID             = oi.OID
INNER JOIN Product      p ON oi.ProductID      = p.PID
INNER JOIN Manufacturer m ON p.Manufacturer_ID = m.MID
WHERE o.Purchase_Date = 2009 
  AND m.Mnufacturer_Name = "Honeywell"
  AND m.Manufacturerd_Date = 1968
```

However, in the query you posted:

```
SELECT * FROM Customer
WHERE CID IN
    (SELECT Customer_ID FROM Order
     WHERE Purchase_Date = 2009 
     AND EXISTS
        (SELECT * FROM Order_Items, Product, Manufacturer
         WHERE OID = OID AND Product_ID = PID AND MID = Manufacturer_ID AND
         Mnufacturer_Name = "Honeywell" AND Manufacturerd_Date = 1968));
```

You are using the `IN` predicate and also joining the three tables `Order_Items`, `Product` and `Manufacturer` using the old join syntax `.. FROM Order_Items, Product, Manufacturer  WHERE OID = OID AND Product_ID = PID AND MID = Manufacturer_ID`

Your query might work. But if there are any `NULL` values for the `Customer_ID` then it won't return any results. But it will be easier to use `JOIN` instead. Here is a useful likes about `JOIN`:

- [**A Visual Explanation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html).
- [**Visual Representation of SQL Joins**](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins).

Comment: You should use DISTINCT so you don't get lots of duplicate rows.

Comment: They didn't teach me about this join thing yet. Does my sql also return the correct answer? thanks.